# YII ERROR - Trying to get property 'alias' of non-object

Tags: php, yii2

I'm new in Yii development and I am getting an error followed by Trying to get property of non-object

Do somebody can help me please ?

```
1. in /var/www/vhosts/sitename/httpdocs/application/models/Profile.php at line 498

   * @param $category
     * @return ProfileField|array|mixed
     */
    protected function getProfileFields($category)
   {
        if (!isset($this->_profileFields)) {
            $data = [];
            $fields = ProfileField::find()->joinWith('category')->visible()->sorted()->all();
            foreach ($fields as $field) {
                $data[$field->'category'->alias][] = $field;
            }
            $this->_profileFields = $data;
        }
 
        return isset($this->_profileFields[$category]) ? $this->_profileFields[$category] : [];
    }
```

Comment: Looks like typo `$field->'category'->alias` should be `$field->category->alias`, if there is empty category relation then error will also appear, check for empty `$field->category` before accessing the property.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to:

```
foreach ($fields as $field) {
    if ($field->category) {
        $data[$field->category->alias][] = $field;
    }
}
```